# extracting data from response present in xml format in postman

Tags: xml, api, postman

I want to extract data from the response present in the form of XML.
[image]
so far I could retrieve/display the content stored within return tag using

```
var responseJson = xml2Json(responseBody);
console.log(responseJson);

postman.setGlobalVariable("XMlResponse", responseJson['SOAP-ENV:Envelope'] 
['SOAP-ENV:Body']['NS1:checkIDDocumentResponse']['return']['_']);
```

but I want to retrieve Gender from the response and save it on a global variable level. Need some direction on how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

solved it!

I captured the response in another variable and converted it again to Json.

```
var XMLResponse = responseJson['SOAP-ENV:Envelope']['SOAP-ENV:Body'] 
['NS1:checkIDDocumentResponse']['return']['_']; 

var Json = xml2Json(XMLResponse);
console.log(Json.result.record.DocID);
```